# Importing a CSV file into Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, vba

I'm attempting to write a macro that will automatically import a CSV file into an Excel workbook when a button is clicked. I've done most of it, but to figure out the import itself (I'm not overly experienced with VBA) I recorded a macro and did it manually.

The result i get is this -

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;\\folder\shared$\folder\folder\TODAYS DATA\Matt\12345.csv”, _
Destination:=Range("$A$2:$E$2"))
```

But what I want to do is change this so it just looks for any CSV file. How would I do this?

I tried changing it to just look for `*.csv`, but this fails as it looks for a literal `"*.csv"` file.

Hope you can help!

Comment: do you want user to select files?

Comment: if so, check VBA Help for Application.FileDialog

Comment: Or possibly search trough the folder for certain pattern use `Dir()`

Comment: No, there's only ever going to be one csv file in there, so i just want it to automatically select that. Once its processed i have more code that archives it.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do this, something like this should work:

```
Sub OpenLatest()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, fs As FileSystemObject, Folder As Scripting.Folder, File As File

    'create a recordset to store file info
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Fields.Append "FileName", adVarChar, 100
    rs.Fields.Append "Modified", adDate
    rs.Open

    'build the list of files and sort
    Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    Set Folder = fs.GetFolder("\\folder\shared$\folder\folder\TODAYS DATA\Matt")

    For Each File In Folder.Files
        rs.AddNew
        rs("FileName") = File.Path
        rs("Modified") = File.DateLastModified
    Next

    rs.Sort = "Modified DESC"

    'process the first newest file
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until Right(rs.Fields("FileName").Value, 3) = "CSV"
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add Connection:="TEXT;" & rs.Fields("FileName").Value, Destination:=Range("$A$2:$E$2")
End Sub
```

It gets all the files in that folder and uses the latest one with the suffix of csv.